# how to do/maintain application edit version control in asp.net mvc 4 razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have created an application using asp.net mvc 4 razor. Like any other application it also has add/edit/delete functions (CRUD operations). This application is to be used by more than one user. So, how can I store and display versions of this application after user edit and save this application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I just want to store and display which user edited the application.

Comment: What are you using to store data, a database?

Comment: MS SQL server, Entity Framework- Code First approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without much information to go on you could do something like this:

**Record table**: Id - PK, Title, Content

**RecordHistory table**: Id - PK, Version, CreatedOn, Title, Content, UserID - FK

**User table**: Id - PK, Username, Email

In your update action (the U in CRUD) update your Record table, then copy the values from the Record table to your RecordHistory table (using a trigger or something), then increase the version number and add the current User's id.